# How Dr. Zhu work on proving Riemann's Hypothesis was reviewed by the mathematical community?

Tags: riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

I am not aware of the logical mistakes or flaws of the Dr. Zhu paper:

Zhu Y., The probability of Riemann's hypothesis being true is equal to 1,

arXiv:1609.07555 (2016, 2018). https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.07555

Comment: There is a sense in which the probability of RH being true is $1$, but that doesn't prove RH. Events of probability zero happen all the time. The probability of a quadratic with integer coefficients having a rational root is zero, but lots of quadratics do have rational roots. See the paragraph on "Denjoy's probabilistic argument" at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis

Comment: I wonder whether the Riemann hypothesis has actually the "almost surely true"-status as Goldbach's conjecture. Has it actually be proven that the random-walk behaviour is realized by the moebius-function almost surely ?

Comment: with probability $1$ all continuous functions on a non-degenerate interval say are nowhere differentiable and somehow the interesting functions that are studied are those that appear in the probability zero case;

Answer (score 4):

I haven't seen Zhu's paper, but there is something called Denjoy's probabilistic argument (for the Riemann Hypothesis) which may be similar. I quote from Wikipedia:

Denjoy's probabilistic argument for the Riemann hypothesis (Edwards 1974) is based on the observation that if $\mu(x)$ is a random sequence of $1$s and $-1$s then, for every $\epsilon>0$, the partial sums $M(x) = \sum_{n \le x} \mu(n)$
(the values of which are positions in a simple random walk) satisfy the bound
$M(x) = O(x^{1/2+\varepsilon})$
with probability $1$. The Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to this bound for the Möbius function $\mu$ and the Mertens function $M$ derived in the same way from it. In other words, the Riemann hypothesis is in some sense equivalent to saying that $\mu(x)$ behaves like a random sequence of coin tosses. When $\mu(x)$ is nonzero its sign gives the parity of the number of prime factors of $x$, so informally the Riemann hypothesis says that the parity of the number of prime factors of an integer behaves randomly. Such probabilistic arguments in number theory often give the right answer, but tend to be very hard to make rigorous, and occasionally give the wrong answer for some results, such as Maier's theorem.

Comment: Excellent answer ! But what I wonder : Is the random-walk behaviour only approved numerically as I heard it ? Or has more been proven ? Can we say that Riemann hypothesis "can't be false" as we can say in the case of Goldbach's conjecture ?

Comment: @Peter I don't think the community is ready to go out on that particular limb just yet. I think there are well-informed mathematicians who wouldn't be shocked if RH turned out to be false.